# MVC POP Up and PostBack

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, popup, postback, reset

I have a MVC c#, signalR project where Agent follow below steps in Application

- Login To application. Once login success application hides Login div panel & displays list of campaign & telephony buttons

[image]

- Application displays list of campaigns agent is assigned to
- Application displays button in front of each campaign to set Ready / Not Ready in campaign. In this case it is RestAPI & Telemarketing
- If agent need to set himself not ready in campaign it opens popup window with list not ready reasons.
  Issue is :
- When Agent select reason and submit it application post back it lost view and reset to login window.

Controller action after submit of breakreason in PopUp window:

```
 public ActionResult SetBreak(breakReasonModel form)
    {
        string tok=form.accessToken;
        string cmp = form.campaign;
        string selreason = "";
        for (int i=0;i < form.arrReasons.Length;i++)
        {
             selreason = form.arrReasons[i];
        }
        SetBreak obj = new SetBreak();
        System.Collections.Generic.List<ISCampaigns> IScampaignNames = new System.Collections.Generic.List<ISCampaigns>();
        IScampaignNames = obj.setNotReadyInCampaign(tok, cmp, selreason);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

PopUp Partial View :

```
 @using Altitude.IntegrationServer.RestApiWebApp.Models
@model Altitude.IntegrationServer.RestApiWebApp.Models.breakReasonModel

<div id="divBreakReasons">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SetBreak", "Home"))
    {

        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.arrReasons, Model.reasonsMultiSelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })

        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.accessToken, new { id = "txtaccessToken" })

        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.campaign, new { id = "txtcampaign" })
        <br />
        <button id="btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-block bg-primary" value="Submit" >Submit</button>
        <br />

    }
</div>
```

Index.chtml

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 table-responsive" id="telButtons">
        <table id="tblTelephony" class="table">
           --Telephony Buttons
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 table-responsive">
        <p id="demo"></p>  // Campaign table with Ready/Not Ready buttons
    </div>
</div>
//ajax call to open popup
<div id="dialog" style="display: none"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getBreak(nrReason) {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
        }); 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("popupBreak","Home")",
        data: '{breakReason : "' + dataToSend + '",accessToken : "' +acc+ '",campaign : "' + cmp + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (response) {
            $('#dialog').html(response);
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
            console.log(response);
        },
        failure: function (response) {       
        },
        error: function (response) {       
        }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It does exactly what you coded. If you need to return result to current view you should use ajax call that will return action result.

example

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "YourTargetForResult" }, new { @id = "ajaxForm" }))
```

You must reference jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js to receive postback in current view.

Example based on your comment:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnResponseMessage" /> // add dom object where response hits

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SetBreak", "YourControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "hdnResponseMessage" }, new { @id = "form" }))
    {
            @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.arrReasons, Model.reasonsMultiSelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })

            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.accessToken, new { id = "txtaccessToken" })

            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.campaign, new { id = "txtcampaign" })
            <br />
            <button id="btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-block bg-primary" value="Submit" >Submit</button>
            <br />
    }
```

Conroller:

```
[HttpPost]    
public JsonResult SetBreak(breakReasonModel form)
        {
        string tok=form.accessToken;
        string cmp = form.campaign;
        string selreason = "";
        for (int i=0;i < form.arrReasons.Length;i++)
        {
             selreason = form.arrReasons[i];
        }
        SetBreak obj = new SetBreak();
        System.Collections.Generic.List<ISCampaigns> IScampaignNames = new System.Collections.Generic.List<ISCampaigns>();
        IScampaignNames = obj.setNotReadyInCampaign(tok, cmp, selreason);

        return Json("SetBreak");
        }
```

jQuery set listener in document ready:

```
    // add dom object listener
    $('#hdnResponseMessage').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function () {
        var txt = $('#hdnResponseMessage').text();
        if (txt == 'SetBreak')
           {
              //do your stuff here;
           }

    });
```

Comment: I am little confused about UpdateTargetId  & new { @id = "ajaxForm" }). I tried with UpdateTargetId  ="dialog" but it display my intire index.chtml in popup . I am looking for when agent select break reason in popup window it should call SetBreak action in HomeController & popup get closed & color of button changed from green to Read.  As of now it opens popup. Calls set break but when pop up gets close entire view reset.  Your support will help me a lot.

Comment: Noe my popup is not getting closed. jQuery set listener in document ready never get execute. I believe I have to write listener  in Index.cshtml. what I expect once SetBreak is executed pop up should get closed. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: It's not possible for me to debug your code without seeing it, but from description you obviously missing dialog close part, what else I don't know.

Comment: yes I think I am missing dialog close but where can i mention that part? Partial view or parent Index.cshtml?

Comment: yes I think I was missing dialog close. Now it's working as expected. Thanks for support